# Git rebase upstream/master - Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches

Tags: git, github

I'm working on a local copy of forked repo.

Before I push the changes I want to make sure that my copy is up to date with upstream/master. This is what I did:

```
$ git fetch upstream

$ git add /webroot/wp-content/plugins/cbp_recycling

$ git commit -m "cbp_recycling added"
[develop 36411f0] cbp-recycling added
42 files changed, 830 insertions(+)

$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       logs/
#       webroot/.htaccess
#       webroot/wp-content/plugins/CBP_Promobox/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


$ git rebase upstream/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        webroot/wp-config.php
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
```

wp-config.php did change as I've added my DB credentials, but then why is it not listed when I run git status?

My .gitignore file:

```
.idea
.vagrant
.DS_Store
```

What am I doing wrong and how to update my local copy to upstream/master.

Comment: Maybe there's also a `.gitignore` file in `webroot/` that excludes the `wp-config.php`?

Comment: `git fetch` only downloads objects and refs from the upstream. You want to a `git merge upstream/master` as well.

Comment: there is no .gitignore in webroot/

Comment: @Kevin when I do git merge upstream/master I'm getting the same error as on git rebase

Comment: Is `wp-config.php` listed when you run `git status --ignored`?

Answer (score 0):

git is telling you that you need to add  also lists of the directories:

```
  logs/
  webroot/.htaccess
  webroot/wp-content/plugins/CBP_Promobox/
```

this depends of the root dir of your branch.

now you can todo this:
goto the root dirand type:

```
  git add -p
```

or if you want add all

```
  git add .
```

to select wath you want add

after you type

```
  git commit
```

and auto start nano for type your commit messages

now for pushing it

```
  git push
```

if is fisrt time push

```
  git push -u origin/develop
```

in any case you're working on the branch develop and why you rebase master?

to enter changes to develop a master, after commit and pushing,you must goto in branch master and type

```
  git pull
  git merge develop
```

hope this help you
      git merge

Comment: I don't want to add those folders. I'll add to the .gitignore but I the problem is wp-config.php which as I've mentioned I did update.

Comment: in that directory is wp-config.php?
you can add only this change with  git add -p

Comment: I think I found the source of the problem. webroot/wp-config.php is listed in .git/info/exclude. I'll post the answer once I got it fixed

Comment: you can add a '#' for comment the line  in .git/info/exclude. and repeat a git add -p

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I've checked the .git\info\exclude file and I found webroot/wp-config.php there. I also remember adding it there now.

However it didn't fix the problem. Git status still returns nothing, so I've ended up doing:

```
$ git checkout webroot/wp-config.php

$ git merge upstream/master
```

Manually update wp-config.php to make sure that everything works fine and pushed the changes to repo.

What is your way of working with git and config files?